# Stop a anchor from triggering js intended for tr/td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html table which should do two things:

1) Inside the tables i need to display some anchors

2) If clicked anywhere besides the anchor i want it to execute a certain javascript

Here is what i have so far:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr data-href="test" >
    <td onclick="alert('this should work')" width="100" height="50"><a href="goaway">asdfasdf</a></td>
    <td onclick="alert('this should work')" width="100" height="50"><a href="goaway">asdfasdf</a></td>
    <td onclick="alert('this should work')" width="100" height="50"><a href="goaway">asdfasdf</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tr[data-href]').click(function () {
        var $parent = $(this).closest('tr[data-href]');
        alert($parent.data('href'));
    });
});
```

So when clicked anywhere inside that table my javascript is executed which is fine. The problem is that when i click on the anchor it is also executed which i would like to avoid. How could that be avoided?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/35761/

Edit: Actually some of my anchors may have a onclick event so that should still work, just the tr[data-href] action should be explicitly avoided.

Comment: You should prevent default behavior example: https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/35754/

Comment: I'm afraid you misunderstand me. I want the opposite. I want for anchor to work when clicked on it, but the java-script popup not to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have more element that has click handlers than just the the anchor `a` and table row `tr`, you can use `if (e.target == this)` to make sure each element type will run its intended code.

With this, `this` represent the element that the event handler were set on, `e.target` the element that were clicked on, and when they match you'll know which one that were clicked.

Stack snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tr[data-href]').click(function (e) {
      if (e.target == this) {
        var $parent = $(this).closest('tr[data-href]');
        alert($parent.data('href'));
      }
    });
    $('tr[data-href] td').click(function (e) {
      if (e.target == this) {
        alert('this should work');
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1">
  <tr data-href="test" >
    <td width="100" height="50"><a href="goaway">asdfasdf</a></td>
    <td width="100" height="50"><a href="goaway">asdfasdf</a></td>
    <td width="100" height="50"><a href="goaway">asdfasdf</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

With this in mind, and if there will be some cells `td` that might not have a click handler, you can stop the propagation on them instead, as if, and someone click on such cell, the table row `tr` handler won't run.

Now, in the `tr` handler, we need to check so the clicked element is not of type anchor `a`.

Stack snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tr[data-href]').click(function (e) {
      if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'a') {
        var $parent = $(this).closest('tr[data-href]');
        alert($parent.data('href'));
      }
    });
    $('tr[data-href] td:first-child').click(function (e) {
      if (e.target == this) {
        alert('this should work');
      }
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1">
  <tr data-href="test" >
    <td width="100" height="50"><a href="goaway">asdfasdf</a></td>
    <td width="100" height="50"><a href="goaway">asdfasdf</a></td>
    <td width="100" height="50"><a href="goaway">asdfasdf</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

If you will have inline script it will be more complicated, where you will need to check in `tr` handler so it wasn't an anchor `a`, or a cell `td` with an `onclick` attribute, which could look something like this, and add `stopPropagation()` to those anchors that have a parent `td` with an inline `onclick` handler.

Stack snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tr[data-href]').click(function (e) {
      if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'a' && !e.target.hasAttribute('onclick')) {    
        var $parent = $(this).closest('tr[data-href]');
        alert($parent.data('href'));
      }
    });
    $('tr[data-href] td[onclick] a').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr data-href="test" >
    <td onclick="alert('this should work')" width="100" height="50"><a href="goaway">asdfasdf</a></td>
    <td width="100" height="50"><a href="goaway">asdfasdf</a></td>
    <td width="100" height="50"><a href="goaway">asdfasdf</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So how can i check in tr handler if it wasnt an anchor a?

Comment: @user1985273 My second sample shows that, using `if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'a')`

Comment: @user1985273 I added a 3rd sample, where inline handlers is used.

Comment: Thanks, i got the idea, but actually went with the opposite and it works just like intended: e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'td

Answer (score 3):

You should use `event.stopPropagation()` https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/35756/

Comment: There is actually 1 more dimension to this, i updated the questin. Some of my anchors may have onClick events, and this solution seems to stop them too. For example: https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/35761/